# get words within text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box with ID `test`. I'd like to log each word within the text box with `each`.

```
$('#test').val().each(function(index) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

How would you do this? I'm aware mine won't work because each looks for actual elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.each($('#test').val().split(/[ \t]+/), function(index, word) {
    console.log( index + ": " + word);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice. Can you explain the use of split? Why did you use `/[ \t]+/`? Are you creating a regular expression to ignore those characters?  Also, not sure if this matters, but it outputs `0` each time as an index without an associated value, then skips past it to `1` with an associated value.

Comment: It's the separator between words. I assumed that words were separated by one or more whitespaces (space or tab).

Comment: Okay thanks. Also, why is `$.each` required first? Why can't I use it as I have above?

Comment: because .val() returns a string, and a string has no method .each

Comment: You can use `/\s+/` instead of `/[ \t]+/` as `\s` includes tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.each($('#test').text().split(/[ \t\n]+/),function(i,v){
    console.log( i + ": " + v);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D7DZZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each($('#test').text().split(/[ \t\n]+/),function(i,v){
console.log( i + ": " + v);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DKBU9/3/)